# Problem with comment box

Tags: comments

The "Reply" option on the comment box is not working. Please let me know how to make that work?

Note: I am able to reply on comments from admin area (wp->comments->...) but the site visitors are not able to reply.

For example check this: [www.linuxstall.com/linux-command-line-tips-that-every-linux-user-should-know/](http://www.linuxstall.com/linux-command-line-tips-that-every-linux-user-should-know/)

Click on "Reply" there. You will not be able to reply to that comment. You can add new comment though but "reply" will not work.

Let me know how to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your header.php file has this before the wp_head function:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
```

**Note:**
Some themes may use the comment-reply function in the themes function.php file.

### Caution:

I've scanned your theme and I notice it's using an outdated version of TimThumb which is a serious security flaw. You can install the [TimThumb Vulnerability Scanner Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/timthumb-vulnerability-scanner/) to do an auto-check, it also updates TimThumb to the latest version for you. You should fix this immediately.

**UPDATE:**

The question continued via email. The theme worked fine on my site which led me to believe it was a plug-in conflict. I suggested the **standard undershooting steps:**

1. Disable all plug-ins
2. Enable them one at a time to reveal the conflicting plug-in
3. Remove the plug-in and find one to take it's place or attempt to make
   changes to repair the issue.

Comment: header.php has `<?php if(is_singular()) { wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply'); } ?>` this before `wp_head`.

Comment: Please help sir!

Comment: I'm getting the error: uncaught exception: ERROR: Permission denied for <http://platform.twitter.com> to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger. Not sure if that helps though. What are you using for the comments? Is it built into the theme (if so is the theme download-able? Is it a plugin (if so which one)?

Comment: I got your comments. They are pending my review. Everyone is able to post comments but they are not able to reply to a previous comment (nested comments). I am not using any plugin for comment. I am using avenue theme. I can send you any file you want.

Comment: I have sent you an email to the "aol" id which you used during comment. I will send you my theme and all details via email, just let me know.

Comment: Send the theme and I'll try to find some time to take a look. If it's a simple fix I'll help you out. I will install it and see if it works on my server to rule out any hosting problems.

Comment: I have sent via email. Did you get it?

Comment: I have installed and updated `TimThumb Vulnerability Scanner Plugin`. Now what to do?

Comment: I got it. The problem is with YOAST plugin.